Problem with horizontalPageBreak with colspan column header
I have used jspdf and autotable library in my angular project to export to pdf. Here, when the colspan range is slightly larger than, the horizontalpager does not work. How to do that where the header is dynamic callspan?
autoTable(doc, {
      html: '#SampleContent',
      styles: { fontSize: desiredFontSize },
      tableWidth: 'auto', // 
     
      pageBreak: 'auto',
      rowPageBreak: 'avoid',
      horizontalPageBreak: true,
      horizontalPageBreakBehaviour: 'immediately',
      horizontalPageBreakRepeat: [0],
      theme: 'grid',
      headStyles: {
        fillColor: [52, 58, 64], // Set background color
        textColor: [255, 255, 255], // Set text color
        lineWidth: { bottom: 0.5, left: 0.1, right: 0.1 }, // Set border line width (adjust as needed)
        lineColor: [255, 255, 255], // Set border line color
        halign: 'center',
        overflow: 'hidden',
      },
      startY: 55,
    });

For reference -- jsPDF-AutoTable/issues/1032
